# Shapefile fails to import into Google Earth Pro

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, import, google-earth-pro

My shapefile fails to import into Google Earth Pro. Is the map projection of my shapefile to blame?

When I heard Google Earth Pro was now free I thought it might be a good tool for non-GIS people to view some of the data we distribute in the shapefile format.  Unfortunately most of the shapefiles fail to import. All of the files that fail use our provincial map projection - EPSG 2953 (New Brunswick Stereographic Double):

```
PROJCS["NAD83(CSRS) / New Brunswick Stereo",GEOGCS["NAD83(CSRS)",DATUM["D_North_American_1983_CSRS98",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Double_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",46.5],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-66.5],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.999912],PARAMETER["false_easting",2500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",7500000],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Here is a simple file that fails to import (1:250,000 map grid):
http://geonb.snb.ca/downloads/250k_grid/geonb_250kgrid-250kgrille_shp.zip

However, the “Aboriginal Lands” shapefile will import fine.  It is produced by the federal government and uses the following projection:

```
`GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983_CSRS98",DATUM["D_North_American_1983_CSRS98",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199432955]]`
```

The Aboriginal Lands shapefile can be downloaded here:
http://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/geobase/official/al_ta/shp_eng/al_ta_nb_shp_eng.zip

Are there certain projections that cannot be imported by Google Earth?  Is there a list I can refer to?

Comment: reproject the data to wgs84 qgis http://www2.qgis.org/en/site/ can do this (GEOGCS["NAD83 not supported).

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps Engine works with WGS84 EPSG-Code 4326, so you'll need to project the shapefile into the correct projection.

ArcGIS: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007m000000

QGIS: http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/de/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html?highlight=transformation